# configuring a backend pool with internal FQDN of clusterIP service

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

Here my manifest of clusterIP Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 6420
  type: ClusterIP
```

And the Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/myapp"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /myapp
            backend:
              service:
                name: myapp
                port:
                   name: http
            pathType: Prefix
```

It creates backend pool with IP address of pods/http settings/health probe etc automatically in azure application gateway. And backend pool status is healthy without issues. 
However, when i add the annotation `appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"`, It doesn't configure the application gateway automatically while configuring the Ingress. 
Also if I change the IP address to CLusterIP of service in backend pool and change the http setting to port of service even without setting up ssl-redirect=true, backend pool status changes to unhealthy.

Is it not possible to use clusterIP of service in backend pool? What configuration am I missing?

Comment: I used annotation appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/appgw-ssl-certificate: "<<cert name>>" to setup https, where cert name is the name of certificate configured in ssl listener of application gateway.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssl-redirect: true
```

wont work, as you also need to supply the certificate for the appgw.
for your second question - I'm not sure what you are trying to do, to use internal load balancer service type must be `LoadBalancer`, but in your case appgw is acting as a load balancer, so you can remove the annotation altogether

Comment: certificate is already configured in appgw. And my bad regarding the annotation, its not in use. I want to know how to setup the backend pool for a clusterIP service?

Comment: i dont think it can reuse existing certificate in appgw, i think it will always try to push certificate from kubernetes. as for your second question - you dont need to do anything special. agic will do it for you